Google Play System Update stuck
I'm using Samsung Galaxy A34 and Google Play System Update is only installed in July 2023, how to update GPSU to get the update?

Considering that A34 was release in March it seems like your device never received any Google Play System update. I assume you are logged-in with a Google account? Have you received system updates from Samsung?

I just checked on my Samsung Galaxy M12, and the row can be tapped to check for the update. Have you tried it?

@Robert Yesterday I received GPSU updates twice, 2 MB and 13 MB, uniquely there was no change in the latest info, it still displays July 1 2023. I still receive the latest updates from Samsung.

@AndrewT. Of course I have tried, and got the update twice since yesterday but the result is still July 1, 2023.

On my Samsung tablet when I go to Android settings, Tablet info, Software info, GPSU version date I can trigger an update check by touching the GPSU entry. Then my   Android 14 tablet just downloaded an 15 MB update.

@Robert yes, me too. But after downloading the update, installing, and restarting, I checked again and it still said July 1, 2023, it didn't change to April 1, 2024.

May be this is a display bug. You should be able to check the installed modules and their version using https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=io.simplicity.trainspotting See also this question: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/230540/2241
